# Cross Apply - Find latest changes

Tags: sql-server

Get:

```
+--------+---------------+-------+---------+---------------+---------------+
| SeqNo  |     Name      |  ID   | ColName |  Start_Value  |   End_Value   |
+--------+---------------+-------+---------+---------------+---------------+
| AAA111 | IronMan       | E8888 | Name    | CaptainMarvel | IronMan       |
| AAA111 | CaptainMarvel | E8888 | Name    | TaeYeon       | CaptainMarvel |
| AAA111 | TaeYeon       | E8888 | Name    | JungKook      | TaeYeon       |
| AAA111 | IronMan       | E8888 | Gender  | L             | P             |
| BBB222 | V             | D2222 | Name    | Jin           | V             |
+--------+---------------+-------+---------+---------------+---------------+
```

Expected result:

```
+-------+---------------+-------+---------+---------------+---------------+
| SeqNo |     Name      |  ID   | ColName |  From_Value   |   To_Value    |
+-------+---------------+-------+---------+---------------+---------------+
| A123  | IronMan       | E8888 | Name    | CaptainMarvel | IronMan       |
| A123  | IronMan       | E8888 | Gender  | L             | P             |
| B456  | DOTS          | D2222 | Name    | DOTS          | DOTS          |
+-------+---------------+-------+---------+---------------+---------------+
```

I have created some sample here : [SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8d9d9db5ee0603652ca3b028137aa5ad)

Based on the fiddle, it captured all changes but I just need find the latest changes based on ID and ColName. In other words, if there is multiple changes for same column and same ID, it will captures the most recent changes as showing for E8888.

Comment: Fiddles are nice to have, but your question needs to be worded so that it can be understood and answered without it, so that when the link goes dead the question will still be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly you could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT RowNum,ColSeq, q.SeqNo, q.ToName AS Name, q.ID, ca.ColName
       ,ca.Start_Value, ca.End_Value 
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, ColName ORDER BY Rownum) AS rn
 FROM
 (
  SELECT  a1.ID, a1.SeqNo, a1.NameReason, a1.GenderReason, a1.RowNum, 
   a2.Name as FromName, a1.Name as ToName,
   a2.Gender AS FromGender, a1.Gender AS ToGender
  FROM A a1
  JOIN A a2 ON (a2.ID = a1.ID AND a2.RowNum = a1.RowNum + 1)
  WHERE (a1.NameReason IS NOT NULL OR a1.GenderReason IS NOT NULL)
 ) q
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
  (1, 'Name', NameReason, FromName, ToName), 
  (2, 'Gender', GenderReason, FromGender, ToGender)
 ) ca (ColSeq, ColName, Reason, Start_Value, End_Value)
 WHERE ca.Reason IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT SeqNo, Name, ID, ColName, Start_Value, End_Value
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY SeqNo, ColSeq;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5c714954ecd98b0002992be724bbcb5d)**